# Laravel BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method [package] when running composer update

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I am trying to use this package https://github.com/laracasts/Validation in my Laravel 4.2 project.

This is my `composer.json` file entry:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "laracasts/validation": "~1.0"
},
```

Now when I run the **composer update** command, I get the following error at the end:

```
{  
  "error":{  
    "type":"BadMethodCallException",
    "message":"Call to undefined method [package]",
    "file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\project-name\\vendor\\illuminate\\support\\ServiceProvider.php",
    "line":111
  }
}{  
  "error":{  
    "type":"BadMethodCallException",
    "message":"Call to undefined method [package]",
    "file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\project-name\\vendor\\illuminate\\support\\ServiceProvider.php",
    "line":111
  }
}
```

This is the full output:

```
C:\wamp\www\project-name>composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
{"error":{"type":"BadMethodCallException","message":"Call to undefined method [package]","file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\project-name\\vendor\\illuminate\\support\\ServiceProvider.php","line":111}}{"error":{"type":"BadMethodCallException","message":"Call to undefined method [package]","file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\project-name\\vendor\\illuminate\\support\\ServiceProvider.php","line":111}}
C:\wamp\www\project-name>
```

Any idea what this is about and how to fix it?

Comment: Make sure you use the latest version of composer. `composer self-update`

Comment: I think the problem occurs when this code is executed behind the scene: `php artisan dump-auto` (because `composer update` on it's own works fine - see above output)

Comment: `composer self-update` fixed the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm gonna write an answer so you can accept it and the solution is more visible for future visitors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you use the **latest version** of composer. Use the `self-update` command to update composer itself to its newest version.

```
composer self-update
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using Laravel 4.2 and not Laravel 5?

Laravel 5 is not even in alpha yet, so things can break at any moment.

[Currently, laravel 5 packages are completely broken](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/3a0afc20f25ad3bed640ff1a14957f972d123cf7).

Comment: Turned out, I was using an outdated composer installation. Running self-update fixed the problem.